# how can i check connection to oracle db 12c using a perl script

Tags: oracle, docker, perl

I have an oracle db 12c running in a container. 
What i am trying do is check connection to a oracle db  using a perl script running in another container using the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;

$\="\n";

print "Connecting to DB..";


my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:ORCLCDB',  'books_admin', 'MyPassword') or
          die "Cannot connect to DB => " . DBI->errstr;
```

where books_admin is my username and MyPassword is my password ORCLCDB is my database name 
But when i ran this script im getting the following error

```
"ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specifiedenter"
```

This is my tnsname.ora file place in perl container.

```
ORAC =
 (DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle)(PORT = 1522))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = ORCLCDB)
)
 )

LISTENER_ORAC =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle)(PORT = 1522))
```

Comment: Ref. the [doc](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle): "If the database is defined in a `TNSNAMES.ORA` file, you can use the service name given in the file" i.e.: `$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:host=foobar;sid=DB;port=1521', 'scott/tiger', '');`. Ref. your  `tnsnames.ora` configuration the `SID` is `ORAC`.

Comment: Cool, will add it as an answer, might help someone else someday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref. the [doc](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle): "If the database is defined in a `TNSNAMES.ORA` file, you can use the service name given in the file."

For example: `$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:host=foobar;sid=DB;port=1521', 'scott/tiger', '');`

The service identifier is `ORAC` referring to your `tnsnames.ora` entry.